# Telerik Framework does not see Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, testing, telerik

To test the use NUnit + Telerik Framework

Browser: Google Chrome v24 + standard extension of Telerik

When you run the test - an error "Failed SetUp: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Chrome browser is not installed on this machine TearDown: System.NullReferenc"

Reinstall Telerik and Google Chrome did not help.

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Translated by Google Translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

Cause of error - Telerik does not work with Google Chrome v.24

Installed Chrome v.20 - it worked

**UPD:**
After the automatic browser update to version 24 - Telerik is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Re-install chrome, and do not say yes to the UAC prompt. What is most likely happening if chrome was installed with admin privileges so it installed to program files. Telerik's testing framework expects chrome to be installed in %appdata%. By saying no to the UAC prompt and yes to the install without admin prompt chrome will revert back to installing in %appdata%